# iOS: loading a UIView inside another UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, loading

I am trying to load a UIView inside another view.

view01 is set to take 50% vertical space on the main view. view01 is attached to an outlet. I will be using view01 to load various views on top of it. Now I am able to load view02 from an alternate xib file.

The problem is that sometimes it works and some times it doesn't. And it's doing this without any change to the data used in the app. So I am wondering what could be the reason for this intermittent problem?

This is the code to load:

```
statsView = [[StatsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StatsViewController" bundle:nil];
[statsView setRiftIndex:riftIndex.characterSheet];
[statsView activateEditing:NO];
[listView addSubview:statsView.view];
```

Can't post images yet :(

The StatsViewController.xib has the StatsViewController class as the file-owner in the xib.

Comment: listview is iboutlet uiview *listview in the h file. the sub view does get attached and it does fire the viewDidload of the statviewcontroller. but the view its self fails to be visible or even fire the tableview datasource methods when it fail to show the view.

Comment: the ststviewcontroller.xib as been setup with as UIView < UIScrollView  < UITableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. there was 2 xib files with the same name, one was from a previous test I had done. and the linker would alternate from one to the other every time I ran it. I was sure I had deleted the file before but it seams I had only removed the reference.